# working with numeric input field in js

Tags: javascript, input, numeric

i have a form in wich i have several input...
one of them should be a number input type.

i use this code to get only numeric input in a input type.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function isNumberKey(evt){
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
        if ((charCode > 31) && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

but i need another features that i still not able to "create"...

i have an input type (example : ) and onkeyup event i call this function (isNumberKey - allowing only numeric input).
in case the number wrote is composed by 4 or more numbers i'd like to return (on the same input) the string with the dot notation every 3 number... ex. 900->900 but 1234 -> 1.234 or 15000 -> 15.000.

Comment: Please make it clear, your question is not clear.

Comment: i have an input type (example : <input type="text">) and on key up event i call this function (isNumberKey).

in case the number wrote is composed by 4 or more numbers i'd like to return the string with the dot notation every 3 number...
ex. 900->900 but 1234 -> 1.234 or 15000 -> 15.000.

Comment: you should seperate both processes - (1)filtered input and (2)formatting. I think you should format numbers as soon as the component looses focus or the user hits enter. you can use number formatting tools already available. look for instance [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068284/format-numbers-in-javascript) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327046/jquery-number-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

**[This might be the answer of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21966669/jquery-restricting-certain-numbers-from-being-typed-in-a-bootstrap-input)** to make the input strictly numeric and allow `.(dot)` with it.
**Make your `show the number insert with a dot every 3 number, like this : 100000 -> 100.000. how?` part of question clear**

***UPDATE***
Though not a perfect solution **[try this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4FLRy/4/)**
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990512/add-comma-to-numbers-every-three-digits-using-jquery)

Comment: i want to show something like this...the user can write only number in this input type (i use the "number" type, but i see that not all the browser supper this html5 feature).

so i use the function above, to allow only the numeric input.

also i'd like to show to the user that every "thousand" the input type "change" and i add a "dot" on the number....creating something like this :

input 1 -> return 1
input 10 -> return 10
input 100 -> return 100
input 1000 -> return 1.000

Comment: do you mean separate thousand's... By `.(dot) or ,(comma)`..?

Comment: yes i mean this...sepate by .(dot) (by is this really relevant if dot or comma..? o_O)

Comment: thanks everybody, i find this:

http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/numberFormatPage2.html