# how can i validate the real numbers using regular expressions in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is my code i have tried this but i didn't get the proper output. I want to give input like 10.00,100.00,1,000.00,10,000.00
How to validate this

```
<input type="text" name="depo_amt" id="depo_amt"  maxlength="70" placeholder="10.00"onclick="formatNumber()"/>`

function formatNumber()
        {
         var regex  = ^[0-9]\d{0,9}(\.\d{1,2})?%?$;

                if (depo_amount.value=='regex')
                          {
                              alert("Number is valid");
                               return false;
                         }
else
{
alert("Number is not valid");
}
```

}

Comment: should it always start with 1 and have all zeroes ?

Comment: it should start with any number than ZERO

Comment: Could you not just use `<input type="number" ...`?

Comment: no i have to validate from javascript statetments either this number is valid or not? if i enter any character it should say u entered wrong input

Comment: can u pls give the full example?

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21984440/2260614).. It might help...!!

Comment: if i give <input type=number"> it ll get increment by one.. if the user goes to enter for 1lakh rupee he has to wait till it will 1,00,000 right?? how can the user wait that much time?

Comment: no, when u r going write some u ll write 100.00,1,000.00 right?

Comment: ill not get the solution well!! i ll try!!

Answer (score 2):

this regex will do that for you

```
^[1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*\.\d{2}$
```

http://regex101.com/r/uY3fS5

Comment: Less convoluted than mine, does the same job. +1 from me :).

Answer (score 1):

this will work hopefully..

please check and tell if anyone finds any descipancy

```
^[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d\d\d)*\.\d{2}$
```

http://regex101.com/r/dS1zZ0

Comment: yeah, I can see it now, haha

Comment: if i give input as xyz123 its taking i don't want that